# Returning duplicate characters in a string

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby. As part of my HW, I am to find the first occurence of two duplicate characters in a row in a string, and return the duplicated character. This is what I came up with:

```
require 'set'

def find_a_dup_using_set(arr)
   s = Set.new
   arr.find { |e| !s.add?(e) }
end
 p find_a_dup_using_set(["q", "q", "c", "d", "e"])
```

Question: was this the best approach?  Maybe because I am still learning, but I feel this isn't what they were asking for, but this is what I knew what worked based on research I did.  Is there a reason not to use an array for something like this?

Comment: An array Is a great data structure for searching elements in O(n) complexity, since there is indexing so it will take a linear complexity for an element to be found. Of course, if you are trying to look up at a string for a duplicate, then you can make the string to an CharArray and after that search thoughout each char.

Comment: @EdwardchoVaklinov: exactly, array's linear search will result in a O(N^2) here. Not a very good time complexity.

Comment: Another way, that does not use a regex, is `arr = 'abccdd'.each_char.each_cons(2).find { |c1,c2| c1==c2 } #=> ["c", "c"]; arr.first unless arr.nil? #=> "c"`. If the string contained no consecutive characters that are equal, `arr #=> nil`, in which case `arr.first unless arr.nil?` would return `nil`. See [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)...

Comment: ...I am not advocating this approach over the use of a regex; I just wanted to bring it to your attention. Incidentally, SO's mandate is to fix broken code and propose alternative algorithmic alternatives; SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place to take working code (such as yours) that you wish to improve. That may account for the vote to close the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: duplicate chars being adjacent to each other is a corner case here, I think (it's a common interview question)

Comment: Your question references a string but the argument of your method is an array. Best to make the a string. If `str` is the argument, then `str.each_char.find { |e| !s.add?(e) }`. I presume by `"...of two duplicate characters..."` you mean at least two, rather than exactly two. Also, your title is misleading. Better: "Return first character in a string that is followed by the same character." Be precise! @Sergio, I don't follow. Corner of what?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: ah, "of two duplicate characters __in a row__" - looks like I can't read tonight. My bad. It might very well be OP's misinterpretation of the actual problem statement, but given the context here (exercise for a ruby novice), I find it unlikely.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sounds good and thanks for the tips! I am slowly learning Ruby, so it's been a process.  Any feedback is always welcome in my book.

Comment: You can always edit your question to make it clearer as long as you don't alter the meaning. As @lacostenycoder assumes a string is to be modified editing would not be a problem; it would in fact be an improvement. Note that your code locates the first character that is preceded in the string by the same character, not necessarily the previous character.

Comment: @Cholis are you sure your method should only return 1 character? That's what my answer below does.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a simple regex?

```
str = 'abccdd'
str[/(.)\1/][0]
=> 'c'
```

The regex here groups each character and find the first consecutive pair.  Then we just get the first character by calling 0 index.

In ruby there are several ways to use a [Regular Expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Regexp.html) on a string.  So you could put this a method.

```
def find_first_dup_in_string(str)
  str[/(.)\1/][0] 
end
```

Here's a variation on tadman's answer and I'll include benchmarks to compare UPDATED to use `each_char` as per comments.

```
def find_first_dup_a(str)
  d = ''
  str.each_char.each_cons(2){|c| d = c[0]; break if c[0] == c[1] }
  d
end

alpha=[*'a'..'z']
str = ''
1000.times{ str << alpha.sample}

cycles = 100000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(:ruby) {  cycles.times { find_first_dup_a(str) } }
  x.report(:regex) { cycles.times { find_first_dup_in_string(str) } }
end

ruby  0.330000   0.010000   0.340000 (  0.338940)
regex  0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.151719)
=> [
    [0] #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fb6a0bd4c88 @label="ruby", @real=0.33893999992869794, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.010000000000000009, @utime=0.33000000000000007, @total=0.3400000000000001>,
    [1] #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fb6a2601390 @label="regex", @real=0.1517189999576658, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.14000000000000057, @total=0.14000000000000057>
]
```

And an funny coincidence, not relevant whatsoever :)

```
14.0/33.0 * 100
=> 42.42424242424242
```

Comment: You don't need the second capture group. Also, you could use `str[/(.)(?=\1)/]`.

Comment: It's simple if you understand regular expressions. If you don't, tools like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iwDdtU/1) help explain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, I updated my answer thanks

Comment: When benchmarking you need to run more than one cycle. Generally you want a run-time of at least 5-10s per method for something trivial like this. Like `cycles = 100000` and then `x.report(:ruby) { cycles.times { ... } }` where I get times like 5.7 seconds for the first and 0.096s for the latter, a very stark difference!

Comment: @tadman: also replacing `str.chars.each_cons` with `str.each_char.each_cons` speeds up ruby version by ~25x. Still about 1.5-2.5x slower than regex though.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby strings can be turned into arrays of characters, and then you can have all kinds of fun with them:

```
def duup?(str)
  !!str.chars.each_cons(2).find { |a,b| a == b }
end
```

Where that just uses an `each_cons` (*each consecutive*) iterator and finds the first instance of the two letters being identical.

If that's not exciting enough:

```
def duup?(str)
  !!str.chars.each_cons(2).lazy.map(&:uniq).map(&:length).include?(1)
end
```

Where this reduces each pair to only the unique elements and looks for those that collapsed into an array of length 1. `lazy` is thrown in for good measure.

You could also do something a little obscure like:

```
def duup?(str)
 !!(1...str.length).find { |i| str[i].ord ^ str[i-1].ord == 0 }
end
```

If you like binary math, XOR will return zero if the two values are identical as they cancel themselves out.

Or for simplicity:

```
def duup?(str)
  !!str.chars.each_cons(2).find { |v| v == v.reverse }
end
```

Where if the reversed set is the same as the forward set it must be two of the same thing.

Note that some of these can be easily scaled up to *N* characters as the `2` is completely arbitrary.

As an exercise you may want to [benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) these routines with strings of varying lengths. Some approaches might not be viable on huge strings.

Comment: Nice but you're method returns a boolean when OP method returns the first dupe character .  Your last method has a typo `chrs` should be `chars`